# Do you guys think "Citation Needed" would be a great name for this site?

Tags: discussion, name

[During private beta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99/whats-the-elevator-pitch-for-our-site/102#102), many of us realized that Citation Needed would make a *really* awesome name for this site. It illustrates well out desire for evidence, our affinity with references, and it's a phrase that has been [made popular](http://xkcd.com/285/) by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed). It sounds like a perfect match to me.

Most SE 2.0 sites don't have their own names but a few do, like [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), because they have great names. I think Citation Needed is in the same ballpark.

Usual meta rules apply:

- Upvote if you agree.
- Downvote if you disagree.

Of course, if you have a better idea, share it! Bear in mind that [a new name is not mandatory](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), but if we can find a great one we should adopt it. Don't suggest a name you don't believe in.

**NB:** CitationNeeded.com is currently taken, but it doesn't look like it's a site one can't be persuaded to part with. Either way, let's first see what the support for the name is.

Comment: I never liked CrossValidated for the statistical site.  Guess I shoulda paid attention and discussed/voted.

Comment: Seasoned advice makes a nice pun on cooking... but is easily misconstrued.  I honestly wasn't sure what I'd find there (e.g. Miss Manners/ Dr Laura/ Dr Phil type questions?). Same with AskDifferent

Comment: Have you ever wondered if the citations you citate (if that's a verb) have citations themselves, and if those citations have citations, and if they do, if those citations contain relevant well researched data, or just generalised conclusions to validate the author's theory

Answer (score 9):

I like `[Citation Needed]`,

but if that gets us in trouble with Wikipedia, or is otherwise not possible, then what about

`References Required`

?

Comment: [Citations Required], [Links Required]

Comment: Post them as 2 separate questions so we can vote :-)

Comment: +1 for References Required not Citations Needed

Comment: I don’t see us getting in trouble with Wikipedia over that. After all, they don’t have a trademark for that, do they? I actually think the allusion to the Wikipedia tag is very apt, and I agree with your suggestion of the formatting.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I agree. The allusion to the Wikipedia tag *is what makes it cool*. The other knockoffs (references requires, citation required, etc.) don't cut it for me.

Comment: @Borror0 References Required though still has a *double meaning* like Seasoned Advice or Ask Different. It also doesn't have the (very minor) negative connotation of [Citation Needed], in that it is used on wikipedia to mark unreferenced statements (*cf.* Citations Given)

Answer (score 6):

I'm starting to think [Duty Calls], or only slightly less obscurely SomeoneIsWrongOnTheInternet.com.

Named after this [xckd cartoon](http://xkcd.com/386/), which is titled *Duty Calls*, it emphasizes the need for a claim to investigate.

:
[image]

Comment: I have an autographed print in the office just above my monitors... ;-)

Comment: I like the in-joke but I think the title is too obnoxious. We don’t have to announce our motives to the unsuspecting surfer *right away*.

Comment: Wait @Konrad, I am not saying Skeptics.SE users are ever wrong! Banish the thought! I am saying many of our questions are 'I heard this on the Internet. Is it really true?'

Comment: @Oddthinking I know what you mean. I just fear that people who don’t will get the impression that the name is serious, rather than a joke.

Answer (score 4):

I like the name. It also might alleviate some confusion among new posters, who think that SkepticsSE is a philosophical site for, e.g., atheists. (Look at some of the closed questions).

Answer (score 1):

[Citations Required]

yabba dabba do, 30 character counter is watching you

Answer (score 1):

`[Evidence Required]`

I actually thought of that name before even looking at Sklivvz answer.

Comment: Though I actually prefer [skeptics.com](http://skeptics.com) and [less strict rules](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/607/making-skeptics-less-strict-or-changing-the-name).

Answer (score 0):

If name suggestions are still possible than how about:

- `[Sleazy Science]`
- `[Bad Knowledge]`
- `[Imperfect Thoughts]`

Answer (score -1):

[Just the Facts]

12345678901234567890

Comment: 12345678901234567890 would be an awesome name (J/K) ;-)

Answer (score -2):

[Really True?] seems to describe the questions asked here.

Comment: Related: [Is there *really* a reason why so many questions *really* need to include the word 'really'?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/445)

Answer (score -3):

[FactCheck]

describes what happens here

Comment: There's a website named that.