# What is this site's design theme?

Tags: discussion, design

This isn't a criticism, I find the site pleasant to look at.

But just out of curiosity what is it supposed to represent?

I see the ordered numbers above the navigation links and some typewriter text scattered around. It *sort* of reminds me of patent application meets [random sci-fi text](http://zipkoe.deviantart.com/art/Sci-fi-interface-a2-8-black-413767143). I like it but what is it?

There is also "[skeptics]", with the square brackets, what is that? Does it represent a markdown link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The background image represents bits of a scientific paper. The title "[skeptics]" is a play on the name of the site and wikipedia's "[citation-needed]" marker.

We've had many iterations of our design (this is basically the fourth). The [first iteration](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/skeptics-brand-concept-and-site-design) had neither of these elements.  The [second iteration](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/skeptics-brand-concept-and-site-design-revised-design) had the papers:

> - Images are of actual scientific docs, readouts etc. all available for review...

The Wikipedia-style header was introduced in the [third revision](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1478/96):

> I did draw upon the idea of "citation needed" here.

Finally, the design was redone and the elements were kept by the new designer in the [fourth version](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/site-design-updates-are-on-the-way).

Comment: Oh yeah! It *was* dark before, I just assumed I was going crazy. Thanks for the full history and links! It's always fun to watch site designs evolve.

Comment: The numbers reference a popular forgery: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/what-is-no-79378