# Why is the word skeptics between two brackets in our logo?

Tags: discussion

Why is the word skeptics between two brackets in the logo?

Is it because we use to write link texts between brackets and in this site sources are so important?

Comment: Not sure, but I thought it was reference to wikipedias [citation needed] -> [skeptical]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this site's design theme?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/what-is-this-sites-design-theme)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [first time the square brackets appeared](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1478/23) in a design proposal.

> I did draw upon the idea of "citation needed" here.
>
> So maybe this meets both the minimalist (+1 for me: I like modernism) and some identifiable mark (+1 for a unique ID).

FYI: My avatar is still based on my initial mental association to the logo when it first appeared. I meant it as a throwaway joke, and never got around to replacing it.